# I can´t download Adobe flash

Tags: flash

I can´t download adobe flash player, whenever I try it asks to pick an application.  When I do i.e. ¨desktop¨ nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try [installing it via software center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/flashplugin-installer) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using Firefox - click on your FireFox Addon Manager and search for the addon "[Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid/)".

Accept the defaults - this will clean up your Ubuntu flash installation and install Adobe Flash correctly.

[image]

Comment: +1 Flash-Aid is great, I am running Ubuntu from a Live USB (hard drive failed and waiting on replacement...) and could not install flash in any form until I found this post and tried it. Thanks for the information =>